# Using a letter as a valid user input (console project)

Tags: c#

I'm writing an app where the console asks the user a question that has five possible answers (these being a)b)c)d)e) answers). I'm trying to find a way to make the console recognise the letter that the user is inputing and then tell the user whether the answer is correct or incorrect. Here's what I have so far, although it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
        Console.ReadLine ();
        Console.WriteLine ("Q9: Of the following, which is greater than one half?");
        Console.WriteLine ("A: 2/5");
        Console.WriteLine ("B: 4/7");
        Console.WriteLine ("C: 4/9");
        Console.WriteLine ("D: 5/11");
        Console.WriteLine ("E: 6/13");
        string ans9;
        Console.ReadLine ();
        if (ans9 == b) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Correct");
        } else if (ans9 != b) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Incorrect");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Console reads the line as a `string` so you need to check it with:

```
if (ans9 == "b")
```

But you might want to also thing about casing. What happens if the user enters `B`?

```
if (ans9.ToLower() == "b")
```

You're also not assigning the value of `ReadLine` to `ans9`:

```
string ans9 = Console.ReadLine();
```

Another edit: instead of checking if `ans9` is equal to "b" and then checking that its not equal to "b" you can just use an else:

```
if (ans9 == "b") {
    Console.WriteLine("Correct");
}
else {
    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately now I get "use of unassigned local variable 'ans9'" Any idea what I could do now?

Comment: Did you initialize `ans9` like I showed? `string ans9 = Console.ReadLine()` should do it.